# Joins Based on Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq

I am trying to join two tables i.e product table and store table based
my joining condition is product id, here my query always returns 0 as value

```
List<Store> list1 = new List<Store>();
List<Product> list2 = new List<Product>();

var query = list1.Join(
            list2,
            st => st.ProductId,
            Pd => Pd.productId,
            (st, Pd) => new
            {
                StoreName = st.storeName,
                StoreId = st.storeName,
                productId = st.ProductId,
                producRate = Pd.productRating

            }
          ).ToList();
```

Comment: It isn't possible for that query to return `0` - what actually happens?

Comment: Some sample data (2-4 stores and 2-4 products) would be great.

Comment: If you mean that the `query`'s list length is 0, then what else would you expect from joining two empty lists?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something wrong either with your data or how you match the keys:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var products = Enumerable
            .Range(1, 10)
            .Select(i => new Product { ProductId = i, ProductRating = i / 2d })
            .ToList();

        var stores = Enumerable
            .Range(1, 10)
            .Select(i => new Store { ProductId = i + 5, StoreId = i + 100, StoreName = $"My Store {i}" })
            .ToList();

        var query = stores.Join(
            products,
            store => store.ProductId,
            product => product.ProductId,
            (store, product) => new
            {
                store.StoreName,
                store.StoreId,
                product.ProductId,
                product.ProductRating,
            });

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.ProductId} - {item.StoreId} - {item.StoreName} - {item.ProductRating}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public double ProductRating { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
6 - 101 - My Store 1 - 3
7 - 102 - My Store 2 - 3,5
8 - 103 - My Store 3 - 4
9 - 104 - My Store 4 - 4,5
10 - 105 - My Store 5 - 5
Finished
```